# Error __construct() must be an instance of Interface, none given

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing a package for Laravel and I'm getting an error which I can't figure out how to fix:

> Argument 1 passed to Cartalini\Drayman\Drayman::__construct() must be an instance of Cartalini\Drayman\Repositories\UserRepositoryInterface, none given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/l4/app/controllers/HomeController.php on line 10 and defined

Here's my code...

```
namespace Cartalini\Drayman;

use Cartalini\Drayman\Repositories\UserRepositoryInterface;

class Drayman
{
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(UserRepositoryInterface $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function deliverBeer()
    {
        return $this->user->all();
    }
}
```

UserRepository...

```
namespace Cartalini\Drayman\Repositories;

class UserRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface
{
    public function all()
    {
        return User::all();
    }
}
```

UserRepositoryInterface...

```
namespace Cartalini\Drayman\Repositories;

interface UserRepositoryInterface
{
    public function all();
}
```

Service provider...

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('Cartalini\Drayman\Repositories\UserRepositoryInterface', 'Cartalini\Drayman\Repositories\UserRepository');
}
```

And finally my controller...

```
use Cartalini\Drayman\Drayman as Drayman;

class HomeController extends BaseController 
{
    public function showWelcome()
    {
        $drayman = new Drayman;
        return $drayman->deliverBeer();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to debug this please?

Comment: Have you tried to read the error message?

Comment: The message says it all. `Daryamn` requires a parameter of the type `UserRepositoryInterface` but you don't provide one.

Comment: Follow [this](http://culttt.com/2013/06/24/creating-a-laravel-4-package/) and [this](http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-4-develop-packages-using-the-workbench) article for package development in Laravel, I think you missed couple of things.

Answer (score 1):

In your `showWelcome` function:

```
public function showWelcome()
{
    // need to pass a UserRepositoryInterface object here:
    $drayman = new Drayman;
    return $drayman->deliverBeer();
}
```

Since you did not pass a `UserRepositoryInterface` object that your code **requires** you get that error.

Comment: This is not the way `Laravel` works, it's about [Laravel package](http://laravel.com/docs/packages) and this is theoretically right but not right answer in this context.

Comment: Do you know how Laravel works ? Check the link I gave in my previous comment.

Comment: It doesn't matter what I know but it's a fact that you are not aware of `Laravel` and what do you answered, how to pass the dependency here, you even didn't give any example, can you make it right ?

Comment: What is your advise here to fix the problem, any code example ? You even didn't give the right code according to plain `PHP`, where did you pass the dependency in your answer ?

Comment: ^ the advice is on the answer `// need to pass a UserRepositoryInterface object here:`

Comment: ^ it is, if you understood the answer. ^_^

Comment: since class `Drayman`'s __construct had a parameter named `UserRepositoryInterface`, you should've instantiated it with  `$drayman = new Drayman($this_is_a_user_repository_interface_object);`

Comment: Yea yea, but that is too much to write @reikyoushin :-P

Answer (score 1):

it might be a to late, but i had the same problem and **the reason was** my concrete class didn't implement it's corresponding interface class. after implementing it, all went well.
although you are correctly implementing it, so this error might have a few reason, which one of them is what i described.